# JQuery Autocomplete's source from db using json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

I'm trying to make jquery autocomplete input field with source from database, and the data is stored in json. I stored all data I got in one variable, it's look like this :

[image]

and when I set source to be value of that sinput field, I got the whole sentece (which is expect from my example)..but now I know to have three words (first - skijanje, second - vodopoad, third - more) so to have three options in my autocomplete. Here is my code for getting data using php:

```html
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
$obj = json_decode($_GET["x"], false);

$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "user_name", "user_pass", "db_name");
$result = $conn->query("SELECT `title`, `type` FROM " . $obj->table);
$output = array();
$output = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($output);
```

Here is js code for reading that data :

```js
 <script>

        var obj, dbParam, xmlhttp,x , txt = "";
        var i = 0;
        obj = { "table":"tourplan" };
        dbParam = JSON.stringify(obj);
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "All data: " + this.responseText;
                var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                for (x in myObj) {
                    txt += myObj[x].title +" ";

                }
                document.getElementById("demo2").value = txt;
                //document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Only one field: " + myObj[1].title;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "tourTitle.php?x=" + dbParam, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        </script>
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
 <input type="text" id="demo2" value="">
```

for `document.getElementByID('demo').innerHTML = "All data: " + this.responseText;` I got this:

All data: [{"title":"skijanje","type":"zima"},{"title":"vodopad","type":"jesen - proljece - ljeto"},{"title":"more","type":"ljeto"}]

and here is for making autocomplete:

```js
<script>
$( function() {
    var otherPlaces = [
        txt
    ];

    $("#search-loged").autocomplete({
        source: txt
    });
    });
</script>
```

ANy idea for correct that? thanks

Comment: what don't you use autocomplete ajax option?

Comment: I don't know how to use that, I will now try it.

Comment: @SupunPraneeth - How can I put the data I got from my db (using php and js /json) into my array "otherPlaces"...with will be the source of my autocomplete.

Comment: see the example: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

Answer (score 0):

Don't use pure ajax, try something like this:

**jQuery Ajax**

```
$( function() {    
    $("#search-loged").autocomplete({
        source: 'tourTitle.php',
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
          log( "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id );
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<p id="demo"></p>
 <input type="text" id="demo2" value="" name='x'>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
$obj = json_decode($_GET["x"], false);

$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "user_name", "user_pass", "db_name");
$result = $conn->query("SELECT `title`, `type` FROM " . $obj->table);
$output = array();
$output = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$response = array();
foreach($output as row){
  $response[] = ["value"=>$row['title'],"label"=>$row['title']];
}

echo json_encode($response);
```